# Python Stack Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stack

Here is the dataframe of hourly traffic counts for van, truck:

| Date | Hour | Direction | Van | Truck |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-02-01 | 0 | EB | 1 | 2 |
| 2019-02-01 | 0 | WB | 3 | 4 |

Below is the table I desire:

| Date | Hour | Direction | Class | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-02-01 | 0 | EB | Van | 1 |
| 2019-02-01 | 0 | EB | Truck | 2 |
| 2019-02-01 | 0 | WB | Van | 3 |
| 2019-02-01 | 0 | WB | Truck | 4 |

I tried simple df.stack() but failed, should I define more in stack()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[set_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html#pandas-dataframe-set-index) then [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html#pandas-dataframe-stack):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': {0: '2019-02-01', 1: '2019-02-01'}, 'Hour': {0: 0, 1: 0},
    'Direction': {0: 'EB', 1: 'WB'}, 'Van': {0: 1, 1: 3}, 'Truck': {0: 2, 1: 4}
})

stacked = df.set_index(['Date', 'Hour', 'Direction']).stack() \
    .reset_index().rename(columns={'level_3': 'Class', 0: 'Count'})

print(stacked)
```

`stacked`:

```
         Date  Hour Direction  Class  Count
0  2019-02-01     0        EB    Van      1
1  2019-02-01     0        EB  Truck      2
2  2019-02-01     0        WB    Van      3
3  2019-02-01     0        WB  Truck      4
```

Or [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas-dataframe-melt):

```
melted = df.melt(id_vars=['Date', 'Hour', 'Direction'],
                 var_name='Class',
                 value_name='Count')
print(melted)
```

`melted`:

```
         Date  Hour Direction  Class  Count
0  2019-02-01     0        EB    Van      1
1  2019-02-01     0        WB    Van      3
2  2019-02-01     0        EB  Truck      2
3  2019-02-01     0        WB  Truck      4
```